# Allowing routes with and without {culture} (.net core 2.2)

Tags: .net, .net-core, routes, asp.net-core-localization

UPDATE: I got it working - added the following to the routes:

[Route("{culture}/[action]")]

[Route("/[action]")]

Problem is now when I am on /da/about it won't add the /da/ to the links generated on the AnchorTagHelper.

---

Trying to allow culture in the routes. But I also want it to work without (fallback to english).

domain.com/en/about

domain.com/about

I can only get one of them to work at one time. Adding / removing the {culture} makes it work for each.

[Route("{culture}/about")]

Have tried changing, moving etc. everything with the MapRoutes

Any ideas how to catch both routes?

I have the following code:

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ConstraintMap.Add("culture", typeof(LanguageRouteConstraint));
            });
```

--

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                {

                new CultureInfo("en"),               
                //new CultureInfo("da-DK"),
                new CultureInfo("da")
             };
                //options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(DefaultCultureName, DefaultCultureName);
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en", uiCulture: "en-US");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

                options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider { Options = options });               
            });
```

--

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                            name: "LocalizedDefault",
                            template: "{culture:culture}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");                
                    routes.MapRoute(
                          name: "default",
                          template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",//"{*catchall}",
                          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });                 
                });
```

--

```
public class LanguageRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (!values.ContainsKey("culture"))
            return true;

        var culture = values["culture"].ToString();
        return culture == "en" || culture == "da";
    }
}
```